# How do you format the Substring function in Postgres?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
select
    d.ro_number
    ,d.ro_closed_date
    ,d.customer_name
    ,d.veh_year
    ,d.veh_make
    ,d.veh_model
    ,d.op_code_name
    ,r.vin
    ,r.customer_email
    ,r.customer_contact_phone
    , substr(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_number
from public.declined_work d
    inner join public.ro_closed r
        on d.ro_number = r.ro_number
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR:  function substr(text[], integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 12:  , substr(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_number
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 172
```

"customer_contact_phone" is data type "text."

I am relatively new to postgres, but to not to SQL in general.  I am a bit baffled at what the issue is.  I also tried the syntax as in this example

```
substring('Thomas' from 2 for 3)
```

But that did not work either.

I tried changing the function to substring as I was told substr doesn't exist in postgres, but I got the same error when I executed this:

```
select
    d.ro_number
    ,d.ro_closed_date
    ,d.customer_name
    ,d.veh_year
    ,d.veh_make
    ,d.veh_model
    ,d.op_code_name
    ,r.vin
    ,r.customer_email
    ,r.customer_contact_phone
    ,substring(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_number
from public.declined_work d
    inner join public.ro_closed r
        on d.ro_number = r.ro_number
```

I thought maybe it is an error due to the data type being text, but that doesn't make any sense to me.  The values in that column look like this:

```
{7147019909, 5246627378}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Postgres:

```
substring(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_number
```

Note that this uses `substring()` rather than `substr()` (the latter does not exist in Postgres).

If you want the first three characters, you can also use `left()`:

```
left(r.customer_contact_phone, 3) as contact_number
```

The syntax you attempted to use also works:

```
substring(r.customer_contact_phone from 1 for 3) as contact_number
```

Comment: Sorry, I got the same error with that

select substring(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_number
from public.ro_closed r

ERROR:  function pg_catalog.substring(text[], integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select substring(r.customer_contact_phone, 1, 3) as contact_...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8

Comment: @Travis: it appears that your column is an **array of texts**, not just a text (that's what `text[]` stands for). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yeah that's accurate, it's phone numbers and sometimes there is more than one.  I am trying to strip off the brackets, the comma and any numbers after the first one that appears.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thank you.  I was not aware I was looking at an array of text, not a text field.  I used ARRAY_TO_STRING and was able to do the transformation I needed.  Thanks!